# TableCell.setText(String) doesn't set the data value associated with the cell

Tags: javafx, tableview, cell

In my particular case I have a custom implementation of a `TableCell` that contains a `Button`. This button invokes a method that returns a String to be displayed instead of the button. The visual change is done by setting the graphic in the cell to null and setting the text to the String, using `TableCell.setText(String)`.

What I've realized - and worked around so far, is that `TableCell.setText(String)` doesn't change the data value associated with the cell in the `TableView`. It just changes the visual representation of the cell. The underlying data structure is in my case a `ObservableList<String>` that represents a row, and each element in the list is, of course, cell data.

My current solution is to set the underlying value doing this:

```
getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex()).set(getTableView().getColumns().indexOf(getTableColumn()), "Value");
```

And this works fine. But I mean, the code is barely readable.

It seems like the data in the `TableView` and the `TableCell` are entirely separated, since you need to access the `TableView` to set the underlying data for a cell. There is a `TableCell.getItem()` to get the data value, but there's no `setItem(String)` method to set it.

I hope I explained my issue good enough.

Is there a better and prettier way to do this? Why doesn't just `TableCell.setText(String) change the data value as well?

Edit: I'll explain what I am trying to implement:

I basically have a table where one column contains a button that will load some arbitrary data to the column when pressed. Once the data has been loaded, the button is removed from the column and the data is displayed instead. That is basically it. This works fine unless the table is sorted/filtered. Here's a MCVE of my implementation:

```
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class MCVE extends Application {
    private final BooleanProperty countLoading = new SimpleBooleanProperty(this, "countLoading", false);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        int numOfCols = 3;

        ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> tableData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        // Generate dummy data.
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

            for (int j = 0; j < numOfCols; j++)
                row.add("Row" + i + "Col" + j);

            tableData.add(row);
        }

        TableView<ObservableList<String>> table = new TableView<ObservableList<String>>();

        // Add columns to the table.
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfCols; i++) {
            if (i == 2) {
                final int j = i;
                table.getColumns().add(addColumn(i, "Column " + i, e -> new QueueCountCell(j, countLoading)));
            } else {
                table.getColumns().add(addColumn(i, "Column " + i, null));
            }
        }

        table.getItems().addAll(tableData);

        Scene scene = new Scene(table);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * Returns a simple column.
     */
    private TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String> addColumn(int index, String name,
            Callback<TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String>, TableCell<ObservableList<String>, String>> callback) {
        TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String> col = new TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String>(name);
        col.setCellValueFactory(e -> new SimpleStringProperty(e.getValue().get(index)));

        if (callback != null) {
            col.setCellFactory(callback);
        }
        return col;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    class QueueCountCell extends TableCell<ObservableList<String>, String> {
        private final Button loadButton = new Button("Load");

        public QueueCountCell(int colIndex, BooleanProperty countLoading) {

            countLoading.addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                if (newValue) {
                    loadButton.setDisable(true);
                } else {
                    if (getIndex() >= 0 && getIndex() < this.getTableView().getItems().size()) {
                        loadButton.setDisable(false);
                    }
                }
            });

            final Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, e -> setText("Loading .")),
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500), e -> setText("Loading . .")),
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000), e -> setText("Loading . . .")),
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1500)));

            timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);

            loadButton.setOnAction(e -> {
                new Thread(new Task<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String call() throws InterruptedException {
                        // Simlute task working.
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                        return "5";
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void running() {
                        setGraphic(null);
                        timeline.play();
                        countLoading.set(true);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void succeeded() {
                        timeline.stop();

                        countLoading.set(false);

                        setText(getValue());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failed() {
                        timeline.stop();

                        countLoading.set(false);

                        setGraphic(loadButton);
                        setText(null);

                        this.getException().printStackTrace();
                    }
                }).start();
            });
        }

        @Override
        public final void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (item == null || empty) {
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                setGraphic(loadButton);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "`TableCell.setText(String)` doesn't change the data value". Of course it doesn't; that's the whole point. It looks like you are trying to drive this backwards. The cells are designed to react to data changes and display something that is based on the data. In your code snippet, why do you need to get the column index like that? Surely you know the column index in this context. I recommend you read up on MVC design, so that you understand the motivation for how all this is put together.

Comment: As for "Why doesn't just `TableCell.setText(String)` change the data value as well?": because it would completely violate the separation of the view from the data. (E.g. what if your model class had a `price` field. You would want to store that as a `double`, or something else numeric, but would want to display it as a string with a currency symbol. When you called `setText(...)` in the cell, you wouldn't want to update the numeric value with a string containing a currency symbol....)

Comment: Okay. Yes, I do know the column index in my context, but in some cases my custom TableCell could be used for several column, and even in several different tables. But I guess that could be solved by just having the column index as a parameter in the constructor.

Comment: Exactly. Or even just supply a function to perform the update as the parameter.

Comment: Really though it sounds like your design is just wrong. Clicking the button is supposed to change the value, and remove the button... You should be thinking of that as changing the state of the data model in some sense. What actual state of the data causes the button to be displayed or not displayed? If that state is being controlled by the view, instead of the model, your design is likely wrong. (That's what I mean by "driving this backwards".)

Comment: I'm not sure I'm fully understand what you're saying. But the only reason I actually need to change the state of the data model (if the "state of the data model" is what I in the question has adressed as the "data value"), is because the `TableCell` view isn't updated when the table is sorted. So if I have one cell whose button has been pressed, and now displays a text value. that cell will remain the same even two the rows in the table has been moved. If the table wasn't sortable, just using `TableCell.setText(String)` would be sufficient.

Comment: If you don't update the data model, it won't work properly when you scroll (as well as sort). It probably wouldn't work if you removed items from the data either. Remember your UI basics. The cell is just a *view* of the data, and it's an implementation detail as to when the cells are synchronized with the data. So if your data model is not correct, then the cells will show the wrong value at essentially arbitrary times.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you explained what you are actually trying to do here.

Comment: Would it be on topic if I edited the question with it though? Can't really explain it in the comment section.

Comment: Yes, that would not be a problem.

Comment: Updated the question with an explanation and an MCVE.

Comment: Your example doesn't actually work though. If you press "Load" in one cell, and then scroll down before loading is complete, you'll see the loaded data appear in the wrong cell(s). The problem is that you are trying to use the cell itself to store the state of the application (specifically, are the data in a particular row currently being loaded). Apart from violating separation of view and state, this fails because there simply isn't a 1-1 correspondence between rows in the table (data) and actual cells (view). The fix is to properly represent your data; I will try to post an answer later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Background: MVC

Much of JavaFX is designed around a Model-View-Controller (MVC) pattern. This is a loosely-defined pattern with many variants, but the basic idea is that there are three components:

Model: an object (or objects) that represent the data. The Model knows nothing about how the data is presented to the user.

View: an object that presents the data to the user. The view does not do any logical processing or store the data; it just knows how to convert the data to some kind of presentation for the user.

Controller: an object that modifies the data in the model, often (though not exclusively) in response to user input.

There are several variants of this pattern, including MVP, MVVM, supervising controller, passive view, and others, but the unifying theme in all of them is that there is a separation between the view, which simply presents data but does not otherwise "know" what the data is, and the model, which stores the state (data) but knows nothing about how it might be presented. The usually-cited motivation for this is the ability to have multiple views of the same data which have no need to refer to each other.

In the "classical" implementation of this, the view "observes" the model via some kind of subscriber-notification pattern (e.g. an observer pattern). So the view will register with the model to be notified of changes to the data, and will repaint accordingly. Often, since the controller relies on event listeners on the components in the view, the controller and view are tightly coupled; however there is always clear separation between the view and the model.

The best reference I know for learning more about this is [Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html).

---

### Background: JavaFX Virtualized Controls

JavaFX has a set of "virtualized controls", which includes `ListView`, `TableView`, `TreeView`, and `TreeTableView`. These controls are designed to be able to present large quantities of data to the user in an efficient manner. The key observation behind the design is that *data* is relatively inexpensive to store in memory, whereas the UI components (which typically have hundreds of properties) consume a relatively large amount of memory and are computationally expensive (e.g. to perform layout, apply style, etc). Moreover, in a table (for example) with a large amount of backing data, only a small proportion of those data are visible at any time, and there is no real need for UI controls for the remaining data.

Virtualized controls in JavaFX employ a cell rendering mechanism, in which "cells" are created only for the visible data. As the user scrolls around the table, the cells are reused to display data that was previously not visible. This allows the creation of a relatively small number of cells even for extremely large data sets: the number of (expensive) cells created is basically constant with respect to the size of the data. The `Cell` class defines an `updateItem(...)` method that is invoked when the cell is reused to present different data. All this is possible because the design is built on MVC principles: the cell is the view, and the data is stored in the model. The [documentation for `Cell`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html) has details on this.

Note that this means that you *must not use the cell for any kind of data storage*, because when the user scrolls in the control, that state will be lost. General MVC principles dictate that this is what you should do anyway.

---

The code you posted doesn't work correctly, as it violates these rules. In particular, if you click one of the "Load" buttons, and then scroll before the loading is complete, the cell that is performing the loading will now be referring to the wrong item in the model, and you end up with a corrupted view. The following series of screenshots occurred from pressing "Load", taking a screenshot, scrolling, waiting for the load to complete, and taking another screenshot. Note the value appears to have changed for an item that is different to the item for which "Load" was pressed.

[image]

[image]

To fix this, you have to have a model that stores all of the state of the application: you cannot store any state in the cells. *It is a general truth in JavaFX that in order to make the UI code elegant, you should start with a well-defined data model.* In particular, since your view (cell) changes when the data is in the process of loading, the "loading state" needs to be part of the model. So each item in each row in your table is represented by two pieces of data: the actual data value (strings in your case), and the "loading state" of the data.

So I would start with a class that represents that. You could just use a `String` for the data, or you could make it more general by making it a generic class. I'll do the latter. A good implementation will also keep the two states consistent: if the data is `null` and we have not explicitly stated it is loading, we consider it not loaded; if the data is non-null, we consider it loaded. So we have:

```
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;

public class LazyLoadingData<T> {

    public enum LoadingState { NOT_LOADED, LOADING, LOADED }

    private final ObjectProperty<T> data = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(null);
    private final ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<LoadingState> loadingState 
        = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(LoadingState.NOT_LOADED);

    public LazyLoadingData(T data) {

        // listeners to keep properties consistent with each other:

        this.data.addListener((obs, oldData, newData) -> {
            if (newData == null) {
                loadingState.set(LoadingState.NOT_LOADED);
            } else {
                loadingState.set(LoadingState.LOADED);
            }
        });
        this.loadingState.addListener((obs, oldState, newState) -> {
            if (newState != LoadingState.LOADED) {
                this.data.set(null);
            }
        });

        this.data.set(data);
    }

    public LazyLoadingData() {
        this(null);
    }

    public void startLoading() {
        loadingState.set(LoadingState.LOADING);
    }

    public final ObjectProperty<T> dataProperty() {
        return this.data;
    }


    public final T getData() {
        return this.dataProperty().get();
    }


    public final void setData(final T data) {
        this.dataProperty().set(data);
    }


    public final ReadOnlyObjectProperty<LoadingState> loadingStateProperty() {
        return this.loadingState.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }


    public final LazyLoadingData.LoadingState getLoadingState() {
        return this.loadingStateProperty().get();
    }

}
```

The model here will just be an `ObservableList<List<LazyLoadingData<String>>>`, so each cell is a `LazyLoadingData<String>` and each row is a list of them.

To make this properly MVC, let's have a separate controller class which has a way of updating data in the model:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import javafx.concurrent.Task;

public class LazyLoadingDataController {
    // data model:
    private final List<List<LazyLoadingData<String>>> data ;

    private final Random rng = new Random();

    private final Executor exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(r -> {
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.setDaemon(true);
        return t ;
    });

    public LazyLoadingDataController(List<List<LazyLoadingData<String>>> data) {
        this.data = data ;
    }

    public void loadData(int column, int row) {
        Task<String> loader = new Task<String>() {
            @Override
            protected String call() throws InterruptedException {
                int value = rng.nextInt(1000);
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                return "Data: "+value;
            }
        };
        data.get(row).get(column).startLoading();
        loader.setOnSucceeded(e -> data.get(row).get(column).setData(loader.getValue()));
        exec.execute(loader);
    }
}
```

Now our cell implementation is pretty straightforward. The only tricky part is that each item has two properties, and we actually need to observe both of those properties and update the cell if either of them changes. We need to be careful to remove listener from items the cell is no longer displaying. So the cell looks like:

```
import java.util.List;

import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class LazyLoadingDataCell<T> 
    extends TableCell<List<LazyLoadingData<T>>, LazyLoadingData<T>>{

    private final Button loadButton = new Button("Load");


    private final Timeline loadingAnimation = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, e -> setText("Loading")),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500), e -> setText("Loading.")),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000), e -> setText("Loading..")),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1500), e -> setText("Loading..."))
    );

    public LazyLoadingDataCell(LazyLoadingDataController controller, int columnIndex) {
        loadingAnimation.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        loadButton.setOnAction(e -> controller.loadData(columnIndex, getIndex()));


        // listener for observing either the dataProperty()
        // or the loadingStateProperty() of the current item:
        ChangeListener<Object> listener = (obs, oldState, newState) -> doUpdate();

        // when the item changes, remove and add the listener:
        itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldItem, newItem) -> {
            if (oldItem != null) {
                oldItem.dataProperty().removeListener(listener);
                oldItem.loadingStateProperty().removeListener(listener);
            }
            if (newItem != null) {
                newItem.dataProperty().addListener(listener);
                newItem.loadingStateProperty().addListener(listener);
            }
            doUpdate();
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(LazyLoadingData<T> item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        doUpdate();
    }

    private void doUpdate() {
        if (isEmpty() || getItem() == null) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            LazyLoadingData.LoadingState state = getItem().getLoadingState();
            if (state == LazyLoadingData.LoadingState.NOT_LOADED) {
                loadingAnimation.stop();
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(loadButton);
            } else if (state == LazyLoadingData.LoadingState.LOADING) {
                setGraphic(null);
                loadingAnimation.play();
            } else if (state == LazyLoadingData.LoadingState.LOADED) {
                loadingAnimation.stop();
                setGraphic(null);
                setText(getItem().getData().toString());
            }           
        }
    }

}
```

Note how

1. The cell contains no *state*. The fields in the cell are entirely related to the display of data (a button and an animation).
2. The action of the button doesn't (directly) change anything in the view. It simply tells the controller to update the data in the model. Because the cell (view) is observing the model, when the model changes, the view updates.
3. The model also changes independently of user action, when the task in the controller completes. Because the view is observing the model for changes, it updates automatically.

Finally an example using this. There is not much unexpected here, we just create a model (`ObservableList` of `List<LazyLoadingData<String>>`), create a controller, and then a table with some columns.

```
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LazyLoadingTableExample extends Application {

    private final int numCols = 3 ;
    private final int numRows = 100 ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        TableView<List<LazyLoadingData<String>>> table = new TableView<>();

        // data model:
        ObservableList<List<LazyLoadingData<String>>> data 
            = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        table.setItems(data);

        LazyLoadingDataController controller = new LazyLoadingDataController(data);

        // build data:
        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {

            ObservableList<LazyLoadingData<String>> row 
                = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

            for (int j = 0 ; j < numCols - 1 ; j++) {
                row.add(new LazyLoadingData<>("Cell ["+j+", "+i+"]"));
            }
            row.add(new LazyLoadingData<>());

            data.add(row);
        }

        for (int i = 0 ; i < numCols ; i++) {
            table.getColumns().add(createColumn(controller, i));
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(table, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private TableColumn<List<LazyLoadingData<String>>,LazyLoadingData<String>> 
        createColumn(LazyLoadingDataController controller, int columnIndex) {

        TableColumn<List<LazyLoadingData<String>>,LazyLoadingData<String>> col 
            = new TableColumn<>("Column "+columnIndex);

        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
            new SimpleObjectProperty<>(cellData.getValue().get(columnIndex)));

        col.setCellFactory(tc -> 
            new LazyLoadingDataCell<>(controller, columnIndex));

        return col ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer this so thoroughly. I just have one follow-up question: If I'd like to have the loading button being disabled depending on the value of e.g. the first column, and also I'd like all loading buttons disabled when one row is loading. Where would I put this logic in this MVC example? I'd be very grateful if you can update your answer with the logic if you have time, or if you can just point me in the general direction.

Comment: My thinking is that it should been in the model class. since it provides a loadingState, it could also provide a boolean disabledProperty. And then the view class should disable the loadingButton when the disabledProperty is true. Problem is that the model doesn't know about any data on the rest of the row. So this would mean that I would have to set some property in the model when I'm initiating the data, right? Not sure if that would be tight enough.

Comment: Consider using a `Service` in the controller to manage the tasks for loading the data. Then your cell implementation (which has access to the controller) can just bind the disable state of the button to the service's running property.

Comment: Thanks. That works! Just found one issue with your implementation. It doesn't work if the table is sorted while a cell is loading. The cell that was loaded pre sorting will still be stuck in the loading phase.